# Common Lisp, list handling (append etc.)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have to manage this situation:

```
(defun make-point (a b)
(cons a b))
```

This function creates one of the point on the Cartesian axis (I omit generic controls for convenience). How can I implement a function where, each time make-point is called, it updates a list where all points are appended?

E.g.

```
'()
((1.1))
((1.1)(2.4))
((1.1)(2.4)(4.5))
```

I will need the list as a parameter for a following function.

Comment: You might have a global variable holding the list of all points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a variable:

```
(defvar *points* '())
```

The asterisks around the variable's name (called "earmuffs") is a very strong convention in CL to denote variables that are declared *special*, which is the case when using [`DEFVAR`/`DEFPARAMETER`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm). Here I am using `DEFVAR` because I don't want the list of points to be reset to the empty list if I ever need to reload the compilation unit in  which the code resides.

Then, you can provide an interface for the programmer to abstract that list of points:

```
(defun clear-all-points ()
  (setf *points* nil))

(defun add-point (point)
  (push point *points*))
```

Here you can see that I store the given point in front of the list of points, which is the natural way to work with lists; appending things at the end, requires you to traversal the list, which is wasteful and most of the time, not necessary. Also, how exactly you append a new element might change how the list of points can be used:

- if you implement `add-point` as

  ```
  (setf *points* (append *points* (list point)))
  ```

  ... then the list referenced by `*points*` is a copy, and if you previously stored `*points*` in another place, you now have two lists of points (I am not saying if this is right or wrong here, just explaining what happens);
- if, however, you mutate the list:

  ```
  (setf *points* (nconc *points* (list point)))
  ```

  ... then you can share the list among different objects, and whenever they read the list, they will have the up-to-date list of all points.

You might also need to consider how much memory you will be using with both approaches. If you append by copying, with [`APPEND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm#append), the previous list will eventually be reclaimed by the garbage collector; if you add points too frequently, you will start to trash memory in a way that can degrade performances.

If you need to put things at the end without resorting to [`NCONC`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm) consider using a queue or an array.
 A basic queue can be simply implemented on top of a list, through a queue object which is just a cons-cell where the `car` is the *first* cell of the underlying list and the `cdr` is the *last* cons-cell of the same list. When you append an element `x` to a list `(e0 ... en)`, you go from this state:

```
( e0 . ( ...  (en . nil) ... ))
^first        ^last
```

... to this one

```
( e0 . ( ...  (en . (x . nil)) ... ))
^first              ^last
```

You could try implementing it as another exercise.

Then, you can keep your function untouched (but indented); you will probably have to make points without adding them into the global list, so it makes sense to keep things separate:

```
(defun make-point (a b)
  (cons a b))
```

If you need it, you can define an auxiliary function which combine both actions:

```
(defun add-new-point (a b)
  (add-point (make-point a b)))
```

Also, please note that whitespace is significant: what you wrote in the desired output (e.g. `(1.1)`) are lists of floating point numbers.